# How to replace text with values from another text file in R?

Tags: r, search, replace

I have a text file with different parameters (par1 to par3 in this example)

```
 101    102    103    
 25     24     23      
 par1   par2     15      
 22     21     17      
 21     par3     18     
 22     30     19
```

I want to replace all the parameter values (par 1 to par3) with the values from another text file.
The structure of the text file looks as below with parameter in first row and values in the second row.

```
 par1    par2    par3    
 25     24     23
```

I want to replace the parameters from the first text files with the values from the second text file in R.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df[] <- coalesce(as.character(unlist(df2)[as.matrix(df)]), c(as.matrix(df)))
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
df
   v1  v2  v3
1 101 102 103
2  25  24  23
3  25  24  15
4  22  21  17
5  21  23  18
6  22  30  19
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = c("101", "25", "par1", "22", "21", "22"), 
    v2 = c("102", "24", "par2", "21", "par3", "30"), v3 = c(103L, 
    23L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(par1 = 25L, par2 = 24L, par3 = 23L),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace_all` by creating replacement as a named vector from `df2`.

```
replacement <- setNames(as.character(unlist(df2)), names(df2))
df1[] <- stringr::str_replace_all(as.matrix(df1), replacement)

df1
#   V1  V2  V3
#1 101 102 103
#2  25  24  23
#3  25  24  15
#4  22  21  17
#5  21  23  18
#6  22  30  19
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = '101    102    103    
25     24     23      
par1   par2     15      
22     21     17      
21     par3     18     
22     30     19')   

df2 <- read.table(text = 'par1    par2    par3    
 25     24     23', header = TRUE)
```